# Is there any possible way to use the Aggregation class with yearly MongoDB request in the java/spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, aggregate

I have **`MongoDB's`** Aggregate query, which allows you to return every status and count them by **year**.
I want to translate it into **Java** `Aggregation` class, using the `mongoTemplate.aggregate()` method.
I try to get JSON with the `AggregateIterable<Document>` class, but my server is loading it slowly, because of 2 or more connections to the database.
I need to do this with the `Aggregation` class, not `AggregateIterable<`**`Document`**`>`.

Query:

```
    [
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "__alias_0": {
                    "year": {
                        "$year": "$createdAt"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "__count_by_value": {
                    "k": "status",
                    "v": "$status"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "__alias_0": "$__alias_0",
                    "__alias_1": "$__count_by_value.v"
                },
                "__alias_2": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [
                            {
                                "$ne": [
                                    {
                                        "$type": "$status"
                                    },
                                    "missing"
                                ]
                            },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "__alias_0": "$_id.__alias_0",
                "__alias_1": "$_id.__alias_1",
                "__alias_2": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "Date": "$__alias_0",
                "Number": "$__alias_2",
                "status": "$__alias_1",
                "_id": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "Date": "$Date"
                },
                "__grouped_docs": {
                    "$push": "$$ROOT"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "_id.Date.year": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": "$__grouped_docs"
        },
        {
            "$replaceRoot": {
                "newRoot": "$__grouped_docs"
            }
        },
        {
            "$limit": 5000
        }
    ]
```

I try many ways to create it, but I can't find the right way.

For example: 
In my database, I have 3 fields - **Year** and **Status (New, Rejected)**.

```
[
 {
  "year": {
         "$date": "2021-08-25T08:44:55.576Z"
  },
  "Status": "New"
},

{
  "year": {
         "$date": "2021-08-25T09:59:49.270Z"
  },
  "Status": "New"
},

{
  "year": {
         "$date": "2021-08-25T10:27:00.003Z"
  },
  "Status": "Rejected"
},

{
  "year": {
         "$date": "2022-01-10T08:12:25.816Z"
  },
  "Status": "Rejected"
},

{
  "year": {
         "$date": "2022-01-10T08:13:07.423Z"
  },
  "Status": "Rejected"
}
```

After sending a request to the database with **Java Aggregation**, I want to get this kind of answer from the database:

```
[
 {
  "year": 2021,
  "Status": "New",
  "Amount": 2
 },

 {
  "year": 2021,
  "Status": "Rejected",
  "Amount": 1
 },

 {
  "year": 2021,
  "Status": "Rejected",
  "Amount": 2
 }
]
```

Comment: Do you expect `Java Aggregation` will run faster than native `aggregate`. Can you provide some sample input data and expected output? What is the purpose of `__count_by_value: { k: "status", v: "$status" }`? Usually it comes with `$arrayToObject` which I don't see in your code.

Comment: Also `$group` followed by `$unwind` is often useless. Many times it can be done better with [array operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators) or have a look at [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)

Comment: I don't expect that ```Java Aggregation``` will run faster than the native aggregate, I don't want to be 2 or more connections to a database.
I want to be an output like: 
```
[
  {
    'year': 2021,
    'count': 2,
    'status': 'New',
  }, 
{
    'year': 2021,
    'count': 5,
    'status': ‘Rejected’,
  },
{
    'year': 2022,
    'count': 1,
    'status': ‘Closed’,
  },
]
```
Like that.

Comment: I read about $setWindowFields, but my server is in the 4.4 version and $setWindowFields is in the 5.0 version 
Is there any possible way to use it in older versions?

Comment: Yes, as written in my first comment, please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: I add some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: "$year" },
        status: "$Status"
      },
      count: { $count: {} }
    }    
  },
  { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: [ "$_id", "$$ROOT" ] } },
  { $unset: "_id" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/weqmPp6FJ59)

Comment: When I request it, it gives me an unknown group operator '$count''

Comment: Try `count: { $sum: 1 }` instead.

Comment: Working, thanks <3

Comment: Instead of `year: { $year: "$year" }`, use `year: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$year", unit: "month" } }` and format result with [$dateToString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

Comment: 'Unrecognized expression '$dateTrunc' - I have 4.0 version of the server, so I add this:
year: { $year: "$createdAt" },month: { $month: "$createdAt" }

Comment: This is basically the same, just little more type work.